# How to Script a Log in System using Pictures on google sheets

Tags: image, vba, excel, authentication

So I'm in the process of making a Game, but we are in the design phase, so were using Google sheets to organize everything from character models and tilesets, then putting them in the respective drive folders once agreed upon, we are coding soon but I wanted the sheets to have a overall database feel so we don't have to create a new one, so I tried to get a script going so that it does this (Step by Step):

1. User A logs on
2. Google Sheets runs a Auto-Log script
3. User A is Tied to Cell A:4
4. A:4 will say "Working" when User A logs on
5. User B has logged on couple minutes after User A, Steps 1-3 Repeat on Cell C:4
6. User B hasn't edited the sheet for X minutes, show as "Away" on C:4
7. User A has Logged off, A:4 will register as "Offline"

Problem is Google sheets scripting is a bit too complex for my feeble java script mind to comprehend fully and structure a script cohesively. I have been really stuck on figuring out Googles Scripting system.

Can someone give me a starting point on what to run and maybe I can finish this script?

Comment: Why the Excel tags, if needed in GoogleSheets?

Comment: I guess since Google Sheets and Excel were kind of the same concept, I put the excel tags, I had no idea about the GoogleSheets tag